# CentOS 7: Stop NetworkManager from adding search domain based on hostname

Tags: centos, networkmanager, resolv.conf

If i set machine hostname to say, `machine.example.com` NetworkManager adds the `example.com` to `/etc/resolv.conf`, something like:

```
search example.com search1.com
```

However, `example.com` on the search domains is undesired. How can I stop NetworkManager from stoping it? I'm aware of the `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` option, just trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl stop NetworkManager` or similar to disable Network Manager

Comment: Unfortunately, I can stop NetworkManager on the machine